# Configuring httpd.conf to handle wildcard domains with *multiple* scripts

Tags: mod-rewrite, subdomain, rewrite, httpd.conf, wildcard-subdomain

I have a full-blown site like:

```
http://www.example.com (uses index.php)
http://www.example.com/scriptA.php
http://www.example.com/scriptB.php
```

I now want to have the possibility of setting up subsites like:

```
http://alpha.example.com
http://alpha.example.com/scriptA.php
http://alpha.example.com/scriptB.php
```

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844004/subdomain-url-rewriting-and-web-apps/2844033#2844033 , I understand that I have to do:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^./]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %1 !=www
RewriteRule ^ index.php?domain=%1
```

But what about the other scripts like scriptA and scriptB? How do I tell httpd.conf to handle those properly as well?

How can I tell httpd.conf that handle *everything* after the 'forwardslash', exactly as it does on the main site, but pass a parameter flag like

```
&domain=alpha
```

**EDIT1**

```
...
I have lots of these subdomains being used, but I placed them _before_ the main 'www' one.
...

<VirtualHost IPADDRESS:80>
    ServerAlias test4.example.com
    ServerAdmin me@me.com
    DocumentRoot /home/test4/public_html
    ServerName test4.example.com
    UseCanonicalName On
</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost IPADDRESS:80>
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    ServerAdmin me@me.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/beta
    ServerName example.com
    UseCanonicalName On

<IfModule mod_geoip.c>
    GeoIPEnable On
    GeoIPDBFile /opt/GeoLiteCity.dat IndexCache
</IfModule>    

 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI}?domain=%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}&domain=%1 [L]
```

Comment: Don't cross post - it really doesn't help you.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve - multiple sites with the same content? Multiple sites with different content? Something else - please specify ?

Comment: Have a look here: [Rewrite rule for dynamic subdomain redirecting each file with subdomain arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631476/rewrite-rule-for-dynamic-subdomain-redirecting-each-file-with-subdomain-argument)

Comment: Hi Iain - I'm trying to have multiple sites with different content, which is loaded based on the 'domain' parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer  MichelZ - that question is very close to what I need. I did try it out today, but it doesnt seem to redirect with the correct domain parameter, as well as it DOES rewrite the address in the browser (which is something I DONT want).

Comment: @All - please have a look at Edit1 which shows the structure of my httpd.conf . I've also setup my zone file to allow wildcard subdomains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all of these URLs to end up at the same 3 scripts - as I surmise from your page-full of data - then you don't need any of this stuff.

Just rewrite to a ***relative*** URI instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^./]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1?domain=%1 [QSA]
```

This will work for any URL.

I suspect you're making things horribly convoluted for no reason - judicious combination of vhosts and redirects will solve most problems without the need for complicated rewriting.

Comment: Hi adaptr - the VirtualHosts point to different test sites which are located in different folders. We're passing parameters via GET and POST and we're using rewritten URLs as well (eg: www.example.com/event/1234/some-text-here )

Comment: I think this is working swimmingly! Doing more tests...!

Comment: Marvelous stuff!

Comment: Ah - little bit of a problem - this doesnt handle existing GET parameters at all... example, calls like: http://alpha.example.com/index.php?asdf=123&def=456

Comment: Investigate the documentation for RewriteRule, especially the Flags part, where it says [QSA]. As for "handling" existing query strings - you cannot do that in a RewriteRule; add a RewriteCond and re-use its results.